Confusion in proof of structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a PID
I'm working through a theorem in ring theory related to Principal Ideal Domains (PIDs) and finitely generated modules, and I've stumbled upon a statement about minimality that I cannot fully grasp. The statement is: "By minimality of $r_n$, you have that $h \sim r_n$." At the bottom is the theorem and its proof where this statement arises.
Now, the confusion arises here: If we have $\langle h \rangle\subset Ann_R(y_n)$, but not necessarily $ Ann_R(y_n)\subset\langle h\rangle$,  how do we derive the statement that "By minimality of $r_n$, you have that $h \sim r_n$"? I can see that if we could show equality, i.e. $\langle h\rangle = Ann_R(y_n)$, and since $\langle y_1,...,y_n\rangle=M$, we would have that $N(h)\geq N(r_n)$ by minimality of $r_n$ [$r_n$ is chosen such that, for all $w_1,...,w_n$ n-sized sets of elements generating $M$, the number of irreducible elements of a generator $\tilde{r}$ of the ideal $Ann_R(w_n)(=\langle\tilde r\rangle)$ is minimised (this number is well-defined since (i) annihilators are ideals, (ii) R is a PID, and (iii) any two generators of an ideal have the same number of irreducible elements in their unique factorisation into irreducibles)]. If we add that $N(r_n)\geq N(h)$, then $N(r_n)= N(h)$ and so (by a remark contained within the proof below) $r_n\sim h$.
Can anyone clarify how this conclusion about $h$ and $r_n$ being equivalent by their minimal factor count is valid under the hypotheses of this theorem?

Theorem 11.22: Suppose that $R$ is a PID and $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. Then there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and proper ideals $I_1 \subset \cdots \subset I_n$ such that
$$
M \cong \left(R / I_1\right) \oplus \cdots \oplus \left(R / I_n\right),
$$
with the convention that this is the zero module if the sum is empty, i.e., if $n=0$.
Lemma 11.23: Suppose $R$ is a PID with elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n, h \in R$, and $\langle a_1, \ldots, a_n\rangle = \langle h\rangle$, and $M$ is an $R$-module with elements $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in M$. Then there are elements $y_1, \ldots, y_n \in M$ with $\langle y_1, \ldots, y_n\rangle = \langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\rangle$ such that $h \cdot y_n = a_1 \cdot x_1 + \cdots + a_n \cdot x_n$.
Proof of Theorem 11.22:
We proceed inductively to show that there are elements $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ generating $M$ such that
$$
M \cong \left(R / \operatorname{Ann}_R(z_1)\right) \oplus \cdots \oplus \left(R / \operatorname{Ann}_R(z_n)\right),
$$
where $\operatorname{Ann}_R(z_1) \subset \cdots \subset \operatorname{Ann}_R(z_n)$.
Since $R$ is a PID, it is a UFD by Theorem 7.21 and in particular this means for every $x \in R^*$ there is ${ }^{34}$ a unique $N(x) \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $x \sim x_1 \cdots x_{N(x)}$ for irreducible elements $x_1, \ldots, x_{N(x)}$. We declare $N\left(0_R\right)=\infty$ and note if $x \mid y$ then $N(x) \leqslant N(y)$ with equality if and only if $x \sim y$.
Since $M$ is finitely generated there is a minimal $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ such that $M$ is generated by a set of size $n$. Let $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ be a set of generators in which $\operatorname{Ann}_R\left(x_n\right)$ is generated by an element $r_n$ (possibly $0_R$ ) with $N\left(r_n\right)$ minimal out of all possible sets of generators of size $n$. Note that $\operatorname{Ann}_R\left(x_n\right)$ is proper since otherwise $x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}$ would generate $M$ contradicting the minimality of $n$.
Let $M^{\prime}:=\left\langle x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}\right\rangle$ and consider the map
$$
\Psi: M^{\prime} \oplus\left\langle x_n\right\rangle \rightarrow M ;(x, y) \mapsto x+y .
$$
This is an $R$-linear surjection; the key fact, however, is the following.
Claim. $\Psi$ is an injection i.e. $\operatorname{ker} \Psi=\{0\}$.
Proof. Suppose that $x+y=0$ for some $x \in M^{\prime}$ and $y \in\left\langle x_n\right\rangle$ so that $x=a_1 \cdot x_1+\cdots+a_{n-1} \cdot x_{n-1}$ and $y=a_n . x_n$ for some $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in R$. Let $a_n^*$ be such that $\left\langle a_n^*\right\rangle=\left\langle a_n, r_n\right\rangle ; \alpha, \beta \in R$ be such that $a_n^*=\alpha a_n+\beta r_n$; and $h$ be such that $\left\langle\alpha a_1, \ldots, \alpha a_{n-1}, a_n^*\right\rangle=\langle h\rangle$. Apply Lemma 11.23 to get $y_1, \ldots, y_n \in M$ with $\left\langle y_1, \ldots, y_n\right\rangle=\left\langle x_1, \ldots, x_n\right\rangle=M$ and
$$
\begin{aligned}
h \cdot y_n & =\left(\alpha a_1\right) \cdot x_1+\cdots+\left(\alpha a_{n-1}\right) \cdot x_{n-1}+a_n^* \cdot x_n \\
& =\alpha \cdot\left(a_1 \cdot x_1+\cdots+a_n \cdot x_n\right)+\left(\beta r_n\right) \cdot x_n=\alpha \cdot(x+y)+\beta \cdot\left(r_n \cdot x_n\right)=\alpha \cdot 0+\beta \cdot 0=0 .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now $h\left|a_n^*\right| r_n$ and so by minimality of $r_n$ we have $h \sim r_n$, and hence $a_n^* \sim r_n$. But then $r_n \mid a_n$ and $a_n . x_n=0$ as required.
Finally, by the inductive hypothesis there are elements $z_1, \ldots, z_{n-1}$ generating $M^{\prime}$ such that $M^{\prime} \cong\left(R / \operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_1\right)\right) \oplus \cdots \oplus\left(R / \operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_{n-1}\right)\right)$ with $\operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_1\right) \subset \cdots \subset \operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_{n-1}\right)$. Set $z_n:=x_n$ and since $\left\langle x_n\right\rangle \cong R / \operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_n\right)$ the result is proved if we can show that $\operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_{n-1}\right) \subset \operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_n\right)$.
To see this last claim, suppose that $r \in \operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_{n-1}\right)$ and let $h$ be such that $\langle h\rangle=\left\langle r, r_n\right\rangle$. Apply Lemma 11.23 to get $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ with $\left\langle y_1, \ldots, y_n\right\rangle=\left\langle z_1, \ldots, z_n\right\rangle=M$ and $h . y_n=$ r. $z_{n-1}+r_n . z_n=0$. But $h \mid r_n$ and so by minimality of the number of irreducible factors of $r_n$ we have $h \sim r_n$ and hence $r_n \mid r$ i.e. $r \in\left\langle r_n\right\rangle=\operatorname{Ann}_R\left(z_n\right)$.

Say $\text{Ann}(y_n)=Rt$. Then $h\in \text{Ann}(y_n)$ means $h=st$ for some $s$, meaning $N(t)\le N(h)\le N(r_n)$. By the minimality of $N(r_n)$ we have $N(t)=N(r_n)$, and hence $N(h)=N(r_n)$, and hence $h=\epsilon r_n$ for some unit $\epsilon\in R$.

Thanks, that answers it
